# Why does this proxy require authentication when used from curl but not from python requests?

Tags: python, curl, networking, python-requests, proxy

I'm using https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py, setting it up with basic auth like so:

```
proxy --basic-auth "user:pass"
```

When I use it with curl, it requires proxy auth as expected:

```
curl -I -x localhost:8899 http://example.com  => 407
curl -I -x user:pass@localhost:8899 http://example.com => 200
```

But when I use it from Python, I can access it without providing any auth:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8899",
  "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8899"
}


response = requests.get("https://www.example.com", proxies=proxies)

print(response.status_code)
```

I get a 200.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `proxy.py`. It appears to be triggered by the fact that `requests` makes an `HTTP/1.0` request with no request headers. You can trigger the same issue yourself:

```
$ telnet localhost 8899
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
CONNECT www.example.com:80 HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
```

Unlike `requests`, `curl` always sends request headers, even when using `--proxy1.0`, so it's not possible to trigger the same behavior.

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py/issues/1267) for this bug.